# mysql | Nested set to select box

Tags: php, mysql, nested

I have nested set table (Joomla categories table):

```
id parent_id  lft rgt extension title
1  0          0   19  system    ROOT
...
12 1          3   6   com_hi    Category1
13 12         4   5   com_hi    Category2
```

How it is possible to convert this data into select box?

```
<select>
   <option value="12">Category1</option>
   <option value="13">...Category2</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  $query= mysql_query('select * from table');
   //select your table first

   echo "<select>";
 // and in your while loop do this code.. 
   while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
    {
        echo "<option value=".$row['id']. " > ". $row['title'] ."</option>";
    }
   echo "</select>";
```

Comment: Thanks. But your code returns: <select>
   <option value="12">Category1</option>
   <option value="13">Category2</option>
</select>

Answer (score -1):

This is a right answer:

```
$sql = ' SELECT node.id, CONCAT( REPEAT( "...", (COUNT(parent.title) - 2)), node.title) AS title
                        FROM    `#__categories` AS node,
                                `#__categories` AS parent
                        WHERE node.lft BETWEEN parent.lft AND parent.rgt
                        GROUP BY node.title
                        ORDER BY node.lft';
```